# Why does the application exit take so long ? Windows mobile 6.5 C#

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

In my Windows application, I do the following when the user click on the power off button :

```
        void PowerButton_ButtonClicked(object sender)
    {
        DialogResult dl = MessageBox.Show(Globals.SECUEXIT, Globals.CMD_EXIT, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        if (dl == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;  //Power off canceled, nothing to do
        }
        else
        {
            Program.btConn.send(BtMsg.OFF);          //Send the turn off instruction to the BT device.
            Program.scr_SplashScreen.exitRequest();  
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

It take ~15s until the application is closed on my mobile phone. How can I accelerate the process ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have no idea what your app is actually doing when it closes. What happens after the `Application.Exit()` call? The runtime has to clean up things - so it has to call Dispose on objects and run that code, finalize everything, shut down connections and any hardware interfaces you've got open, stop all child threads and free up GC memory.  You could easily have something in a Dispose method or Finalizer that takes a long time to execute.

If you don't already have a feel for what's causing the problem, start removing large feature chunks to see which one is causing the slowness, then drill down into it, removing smaller and smaller pieces until you find it.